# Android Cmake about *so depend so

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk

I do not have too much experience with CMake. The current stage, I am trying to import three *.so files to my android project.

```
A.so A.h
B.so
C.so
```

`A.so` depend on `B.so` and `C.so`

My Android module gradle:

```
android {
    namespace 'com.example.projectname'
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk 29
        targetSdk 32

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles "consumer-rules.pro"

        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-std=c++11"
            }
        }

        ndk {
            // Specifies the ABI configurations of your native
            // libraries Gradle should build and package with your APK.
            abiFilters  'arm64-v8a'//, 'armeabi-v7a'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {

            path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
            version "3.18.1"
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

My Cmake is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSIO 3.4.1)

project(MyProjectNative)

# Creates and names a library, sets it as either STATIC
# or SHARED, and provides the relative paths to its source code.
# You can define multiple libraries, and CMake builds them for you.
# Gradle automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
        my_native

        # Sets the library as a shared library.
        SHARED

        # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
        my_native.cpp A.h)

# reference head
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

# Searches for a specified prebuilt library and stores the path as a
# variable. Because CMake includes system libraries in the search path by
# default, you only need to specify the name of the public NDK library
# you want to add. CMake verifies that the library exists before
# completing its build.

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
        log-lib

        # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
        # you want CMake to locate.
        log)

add_library( libA
        SHARED
        IMPORTED )

set_target_properties( # Specifies the target library.
        libA

        # Specifies the parameter you want to define.
        PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION

        # Provides the path to the library you want to import.
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/A.so)

add_library( libB
        SHARED
        IMPORTED )

set_target_properties( # Specifies the target library.
        libB

        # Specifies the parameter you want to define.
        PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION

        # Provides the path to the library you want to import.
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/B.so)

add_library( libC
        SHARED
        IMPORTED )

set_target_properties( # Specifies the target library.
        libC

        # Specifies the parameter you want to define.
        PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION

        # Provides the path to the library you want to import.
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/C.so)


target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
        my_native
        # Links the target library to the log library
        # included in the NDK.
        libA
        libB
        libC
            ${log-lib})
```

I got Cmake link error:

```
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: ninja: Entering directory `/Users/name/.cxx/Debug/j5ga2s2b/arm64-v8a'
      [1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/my_native.dir/my_native.cpp.o
      [2/2] Linking CXX shared library /Users/name/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/j5ga2s2b/obj/arm64-v8a/libmy_native.so
      FAILED: /Users/name/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/j5ga2s2b/obj/arm64-v8a/libmy_native.so 
      : && /Users/name/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++ --target=aarch64-none-linux-android29 --gcc-toolchain=/Users/name/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64 --sysroot=/Users/name/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot -fPIC -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -std=c++11 -fno-limit-debug-info  -static-libstdc++ -Wl,--build-id=sha1 -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-undefined -Qunused-arguments -shared -Wl,-soname,libmy_native.so -o /Users/name/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/j5ga2s2b/obj/arm64-v8a/libmy_native.so CMakeFiles/my_native.dir/my_native.cpp.o  /Users/name/src/main/cpp/../../../libs/arm64-v8a/A.so  /Users/name/src/main/cpp/../../../libs/arm64-v8a/B.so  /Users/name/src/main/cpp/../../../libs/arm64-v8a/C.so  -lmessage  -l(  -larm64-v8a  -l)  -llog  -latomic -lm && :
      /bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
      /bin/sh: -c: line 0: `: && /Users/name/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++ --target=aarch64-none-linux-android29 --gcc-toolchain=/Users/name/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64 --sysroot=/Users/name/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot -fPIC -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -std=c++11 -fno-limit-debug-info  -static-libstdc++ -Wl,--build-id=sha1 -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-undefined -Qunused-arguments -shared -Wl,-soname,libmy_native.so -o /Users/name/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/j5ga2s2b/obj/arm64-v8a/libmy_native.so CMakeFiles/my_native.dir/my_native.cpp.o  /Users/name/src/main/cpp/../../../libs/arm64-v8a/A.so  /Users/name/src/main/cpp/../../../libs/arm64-v8a/B.so  /Users/name/src/main/cpp/../../../libs/arm64-v8a/C.so  -lmessage  -l(  -larm64-v8a  -l)  -llog  -latomic -lm && :'
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Looks like those error is talking about cmake link have problem.Please help to teach me, how to write the correct CMake to make `*.so` depend `*.so`. In fact, I do not have any idea about those Cmake error, Thank you!

Comment: The part `-l(  -larm64-v8a  -l)` in the command line is completely wrong and smells like some problem with your environment settings. And this problem is absolutely not related to the libraries `A.so`, `B.so` and `C.so`. BTW, the comma in `my_native.cpp, A.h` is wrong: CMake delimits function's arguments with the space, not with the comma.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I have removed the comma, this was my edit mistake.